# Accepting input in Django ListView

Tags: django

In a Django website, I have a paginated `ListView` that shows a listing of certain objects, 100 per page.

I want to include a text box on this page and accept+process user input. But in Django, this would require me to either:

i) Use a `FormView` (in which case I lose pagination), or

ii) Write function-based views where I handle pagination and form processing manually.

Is there a third way to achieve what I'm trying to do, ideally without disrupting the `ListView`?

Comment: Why don't you use one simple function-based view where you can handle your list and your form easily?

Comment: @ettanany: yes, by non-cbvs in (ii), I meant function-based views

Comment: I got it. I think your case is similar to this one [ListView and CreateView in one template Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341568/listview-and-createview-in-one-template-django)

Comment: @ettanany: Okay fair enough. If you write an an illustrative example of a function-based view that both paginates and accepts form input, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: So, for the text-box are you using Ajax to send the data and get processed data back? Or are you sending it to django through page refreshes?

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri: page refreshes.

Comment: @HassanBaig Please take a look at the example in my answer (I tested it and it works for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion each view should do have one purpose. Doesn't mean you cannot have multiple form elements in a single page. You can do it by

Make a normal view that would only process the data. You would set the url of the view, and then make an ajax call to that view. This can be easily achievable if you are willing to use JavaScript for that as well.(simple xhr methods, blur,change events)

Ex:-

```
class FormElementProcess(View):
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        #Do your processing and return httpresponse
```

You can further customise the above class and also use formviews for processing and returning of form data, if a form class is also used.

This would be the way out of this I guess. Suppose I have dozens of forms in my Homepage. Forms like -> search,login,register etc. I wouldn't be handling everything through my IndexView. That would over complicate everything when the application would get larger in scale.

2) If page refreshes, then I would suggest you use a FormMixin.
There's a good implementation I found for making **FormListView**

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class FormListView(FormMixin, ListView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # From ProcessFormMixin
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        self.form = self.get_form(form_class)

        # From BaseListView
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()
        if not allow_empty and len(self.object_list) == 0:
            raise Http404(_(u"Empty list and '%(class_name)s.allow_empty' is False.")
                          % {'class_name': self.__class__.__name__})

        context = self.get_context_data(object_list=self.object_list, form=self.form)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)


class MyListView(FormListView):
    form_class = MySearchForm
    model = MyModel
    # ...
```

[Detailed Code Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406553/django-class-based-view-listview-with-form)

You would modify the post method further to do your processing. You could directly use the form class, include parameters from request for processing.

Answer (score 1):

An example of using function-based view to achieve what you want is as follows:

**contacts/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**contacts/forms.py:**

```
from django import forms


class UserForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField(label='Search', max_length=100)
```

**contacts/views.py:**

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Contact
from .forms import UserForm


def my_contacts(request):
    form = UserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Do something with form data here
            print(form.cleaned_data['search'])
        redirect('my_contacts')

    contacts_list = Contact.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(contacts_list, 10)
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        contacts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'contacts/contacts.html', {'contacts': contacts, 'form': form})
```

**contacts/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns(
   'contacts.views',
    url(r'^$', 'my_contacts', name='my_contacts'),
)
```

**templates/contacts/contacts.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block 'container' %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for contact in contacts %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.last_name }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

{% if contacts.has_other_pages %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if contacts.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in contacts.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if contacts.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if contacts.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**templates/base.html:**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>{% block 'title'%}{% endblock %}</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href={% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %} rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 50px;">
        {% block 'container' %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```